# python locals() within function includes class imported outside function

Tags: python, debugging, scoping

Consider the following code:

```
# import a class from another module within package
from .continuous import Continuous
from typing include List, Dict

def build_two_compartment_models(model_descriptions: Dict) -> List:
    print(model_descriptions)
```

I set a breakpoint in `build_two_compartment_models`  and was surprised to see the class `Continuous` listed when I ran `locals()`.  I thought `locals()` would only include `model_descriptions` (and maybe `Dict` and `List`).  Instead, it included:

```
  'credits':     Thanks to CWI, CNRI, BeOpen.com, Zope Corporation and a cast of thousands
      for supporting Python development.  See www.python.org for more information.,
  'license': Type license() to see the full license text,
  'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.,
  '__pybind11_internals_v3_clang_libcpp_cxxabi1002__': <capsule object NULL at 0x1194d12d0>,
  '__IPYTHON__': True,
  'display': <function IPython.core.display.display(*objs, include=None, exclude=None, metadata=None, transient=None, display_id=None, **kwargs)>,
  'interpreter': <_pydev_bundle.pydev_ipython_code_executor.CodeExecutor at 0x128d6d430>,
  'get_ipython': <bound method InteractiveShell.get_ipython of <_pydev_bundle.pydev_ipython_console_011.PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x128d6d8e0>>},
 'Dict': typing.Dict,
 'List': typing.List,
 'Continuous': diffusion.models.two_compartment.continuous.Continuous,
 'build_two_compartment_models': <function diffusion.models.two_compartment.build_models.build_two_compartment_models(model_descriptions: Dict) -> List>,
 '_pydev_stop_at_break': <function _pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_tracing._pydev_stop_at_break(line)>,
 'model_descriptions': {'prms':  None},
 '__builtin__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '_ih': ['', 'locals()'],
 '_oh': {},
 '_dh': ['/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/diffusion_study'],
 'In': ['', 'locals()'],
 'Out': {},
 'get_ipython': <bound method InteractiveShell.get_ipython of <_pydev_bundle.pydev_ipython_console_011.PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x128d6d8e0>>,
 'exit': <IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall at 0x128d6de20>,
 'quit': <IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall at 0x128d6de20>,
 '_': '',
 '__': '',
```

Why is all this here?  Especially `Continuous` which is explicitly imported outside the function.  What am I not understanding about local variables?

Comment: I think that is `locals()` from outside the scope of the function. I.e. it's `globals()`. If you actually put `print(locals())` inside your function, you'll see the actual local variables.

Comment: You're right.  So, why is ```locals()``` different when I look at it in the debugger even thoughI'm stopped in the function?

Comment: this is probably an effect of the deubgger